# Multiple Or's Used In Assignment Vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I was writing a regex in which i needed to assign multiple options for the match, during this I stumbled across a piece of code as follows:

```
Dim options As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
```

This code appears to work as I need, but it raised the questions of what is the `or` keyword doing in this line of code?

It *appears* to be assigning multiple values to the one variable.

What is it's purpose and limitations?

Can the following code be used similarly?

```
Dim options As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline Or 
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
```

Comment: It's a [bitwise operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). Each options are stored in a single bit. Since a variable have multiple bit, the variable can contain multiple options. The options are added with OR and checked with AND.

Comment: About the *limitations*. Some flags (generally speaking) can be combined. Some are mutually exclusive. Some are mandatory when another flag is used. Some don't make sense when used at the same time. The documentation explains their usage and the outcome of their combination. Some documentations don't make sense when combined with a normal brain. But that's another story.

Comment: @Jimi I'm curious more to do with the operator in general as opposed to the regex options. The limitations of that operator when its used in the assignment of a variable

Comment: @the_lotus I under stand that it's a bitwise, but I dont understand what it is doing in relation to variable assignment. Is it assigning multiple values to one variable?

Comment: The operator is just combining flags to produce a value that is interpreted by a function doing the opposite `If [Value].HasFlag(SomeFlag) Then ...` Or `If [Value] & SomeFlag = SomeFlag Then ...`. These values are predefined (Enumerators or value types of different kind). The docs specify what flags are interpreted and their usage.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.8) explain the numerical value of each options. Using the OR operator will do a [bitwise operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Let's take your example. RegexOptions.Multiline has a numerical value of 256 while RegexOptions.IgnoreCase has a value of 1. In binary these are represented as.

```
256 = ‭000100000000 (This is the bit for multiline)‬
  1 = 000000000001 (This is the bit for IgnoreCase)
```

256 or 1 = 257

```
257 = 000100000001
```

As you can see, 257 contains both the bit for multiline and ignroecase.